# how to create an image array

Tags: ios, arrays, image

[i have upload the code screenshot, it has changed when i paster the code i don't know why.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ry4pu.png)everyone. i have download an ios sample code from [GIT](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser),i want use it(ReallyBigPhotoLibrary.xcodepro) to my project.but it shows only one picture here, and i have many pictures, i don't know how to modify it to fit my project ,please help me. thanks very much.

```
//
//  PhotoDataSource.m
//  ReallyBigPhotoLibrary
//
//  Created by Kirby Turner on 9/14/10.
//  Copyright 2010 White Peak Software Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "PhotoDataSource.h"


@implementation PhotoDataSource

- (void)dealloc
{
   [data_ release], data_ = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}

- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      data_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"IMG_0694_th.jpg"], @"thumbnail", [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0694.JPG"],     @"fullsize", nil];
      [data_ addObject:dict];
   }
   return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPhotos
{
   NSInteger count = 1000; [data_ count];
   return count;
}

// Implement either these, for synchronous images…
- (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [data_ objectAtIndex:0];
   UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"fullsize"];
   return image;
}

- (UIImage *)thumbImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [data_ objectAtIndex:0];
   UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
   return image;
}


@end
```

Comment: You have only one object in your mutable array. How do you want to make to fit with your project?

Comment: please .what should i do .please help me

Comment: from where you get images.?

Comment: all local images, i named those images like:img1,img2,img3,img4...i want it shows 10 different images in the grid view,

Comment: then place `dict` creation code in a loop and add all the images in `data_` array

Comment: can you teach me a litter more detail. thank you very very very much. i have no idea now, i have ask many friends, but till can't be solve .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following methods:

```
- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      data_ = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIImage    imageNamed:@"IMG_0694_th.jpg"], @"thumbnail", [UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0694.JPG"],     @"fullsize", nil];
      //Add all the images you have in the data. Currently you are adding only one image here.

      [data_ addObject:dict];
   }
   return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPhotos
{
   return [data_ count];
}


 - (UIImage *)imageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [data_ objectAtIndex:index];
   UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"fullsize"];
   return image;
}

- (UIImage *)thumbImageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [data_ objectAtIndex:index];
   UIImage *image = [dict objectForKey:@"thumbnail"];
   return image;
}
```

Comment: it's not work.you said "//Add all the images you have in the data.."what should i do？   T。T